# How to store the updates of state in an offchain database?

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to store all the blockchain data in offchain database.
rpc has a function called [EXPERIMENTAL_changes](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#view-contract-state-changes), I was told that I can do that by http polling of this method but I am unable to find out how to use it.

```
http post https://rpc.testnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 id=dontcare method=EXPERIMENTAL_changes \ params:='{ "changes_type": "data_changes", "account_ids": ["guest-book.testnet"], "key_prefix_base64": "", "block_id": 19450732 }'
```

For example here the results give:

```
"change": { "account_id": "guest-book.testnet", "key_base64": "bTo6Mzk=", "value_base64": "eyJwcmVtaXVtIjpmYWxzZSwic2VuZGVyIjoiZmhyLnRlc3RuZXQiLCJ0ZXh0IjoiSGkifQ==" }
```

What is key_base64?
Decoding it to string gives m::39
What is m::39?
For example, I have the following state data in the rust structure.

```
pub struct Demo {
    user_profile_map: TreeMap<u128, User>,
    user_products_map: TreeMap<u128, UnorderedSet<u128>>, // (user_id, set<product_id>)
    product_reviews_map: TreeMap<u128, UnorderedSet<u128>>, // (product_id, set<review_id>)
    product_check_bounty: LookupMap<u128, Vector<u64>>
}
```

How to know anything gets changed in these variables?

Will I have to check every block id for the point the contract is deployed, to know where there is the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to store all the blockchain data in offchain database.

If so, I recommend you take a look at the [Indexer Framework](https://github.com/near/nearcore/tree/master/chain/indexer), which allows you to get a stream of blocks and handle them. We use it to build [Indexer for Wallet](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-wallet/) (keeps track of every added and deleted access key, and stores those into Postgres) and [Indexer for Explorer](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer/) (keeps track of every block, chunk, transaction, receipt, execution outcome, state changes, accounts, and access keys, and stores all of that in Postgres)

> What is m::39?

Contracts in NEAR Protocol have access to the key-value storage (state), so at the lowest-level, you operate with key-value operations (NEAR SDK for AssemblyScript defines [Storage](https://near.github.io/near-sdk-as/classes/_sdk_core_assembly_storage_.storage-1.html) class with `get` and `set` operations, and NEAR SDK for Rust has [`storage_read`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/near_sdk/env/fn.storage_read.html) and [`storage_write`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/near_sdk/env/fn.storage_write.html) calls to preserve data).

Guest Book example uses a high-level abstraction called `PersistentVector`, which automatically reads and writes its records from/to NEAR key-value storage (state). [As you can see](https://github.com/near-examples/guest-book/blob/bda4af01ee3bdbaae2cc383b6ec19af59da4e023/assembly/model.ts#L21):

```js
export const messages = new PersistentVector<PostedMessage>("m");
```

Guest Book defines the messages to be stored in the storage with `m` prefix, hense you see `m::39`, which basically means it is `messages[39]` stored in the key-value storage.

> What is key_base64?

As key-value storage implies, the data is stored and accessed by keys, and the key can be binary, so base64 encoding is used to enable JSON-RPC API users with a way to query those binary keys as well (there is no way you can pass a raw binary blob in JSON).

> How to know anything gets changed in these variables? Will I have to check every block id for the point the contract is deployed, to know where there is the change?

Correct, you need to follow every block, and check the changes. That is why we have built the Indexer Framework in order to enable community building services on top of that (we chose to build applications Indexer for Wallet and Indexer for Explorer, but others may decide to build GraphQL service like TheGraph)

Comment: EXPERIMENTAL_changes require a single block_id, it will be great if we can query all the changes between a block_id range e.g. (25671799-25672572)

Comment: @AmiyaBehera I am afraid, it is beyond the scope we want to expose through JSON RPC; considering the edge cases during the network high load (1k transactions in a single chunk with at least 10 shards means that we already talk about 1k * 10 * 2 changes in a single block [2 is sender and receiver accounts being touched]), we can easily hit the limit. Thus, we suggest you use Indexer for those purposes